# Bound services: BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag documentation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

From the docs,

> Flag for bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int): automatically
> create the service as long as the binding exists. Note that while this
> will create the service, its Service.onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)
> method will still only be called due to an explicit call to
> startService(Intent). Even without that, though, this still provides
> you with access to the service object while the service is created.

I have read the documentation on this flag but am not able to understand still, what the flag is about.

Can someone elaborate on it's meaning for the sake of simplicity? It would probably be even clearer if an example is provided to explain the same.